# What's the code to create login condition programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, authentication, conditional-statements

So I created an empty activity, put 2 edit text (one for username and the other for phone number ) and 2 buttons (login and register).

I want my activity to performe the following conditions when the login button's pressed:

When inputting the username must be more than one character and the first one must be capital. And for the Phone number, there must be a certain number of numbers. Not null for both.

If the user doesnt meet the requirements give a toast, and if he/she does send the user to the next activity.

All of this done without the use of a database, just for experimental purpose. Thank You.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to accomplish can be achieved by using string manipulation.

Here are the steps:

1. First, get the String value from the edit text by using the following code:

   String userName = myEditText1.getText().toString();
   String phoneNum = myEditText2.getText().toString();
2. Now, check if any of the values are null by using the following:

   if(userName.isEmpty() || userName.isEmpty()){

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Input! Try again.",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
3. Now to check if the username has at least one character and the first character is a capital, use the following code snippet:

   if(userName.legth() <= 1 || !Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)){

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Input! Try again.",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
4. To check if the phone number has a certain number of digits, simply do the following:

   if(phoneNum.length < desiredNum){

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Input! Try again.",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
5. Now in the end, if the user does fulfill also those requirements, just display a small toast and redirect activity.

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Confirmed!",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.this);
   CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

And there you have it! You should probably study a bit more java and try a few solutions before posting such a question.

Best regards,

Kobe

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm new to this so couldn't do much.